# How to avoid schedule task before status date if i use level all resource in MS-project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I use level all for scheduling resource for entire project but i use it for production plan ,when the new task is come, i add the new task in MS-project. After I assign resource, I want to use level function for scheduling automatically but the problem is it schedule before status date.
So i select the new coming task, then edit leveling range from today to end of this year. After that, i crop the new task and click level selection,  but it still schedule before status date. Nothing is changed.
Is it possible to use level resource function and not schedule before status date or should i coding VBA for solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

go to option > schedule > Auto scheduled tasks schedules on > current date